# Why does selenium webdriver keys work on windows but not mac?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a bizarre issue where the selenium down arrow key fro the "from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys" module works in my windows program but when running it on mac the down arrow line does not execute (the picklist item is clicked, but no down arrow event occurs). This is a really frustrating issue as I will likely be running this program from multiple environments. Would this be tied to the chrome driver version or is there some other solution? here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import glob
import os

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://permits.mynevadacounty.com/CitizenAccess/Cap/CapHome.aspx?module=Building&TabName=Building")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[src='/CitizenAccess/nc-horizontal.png']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_lblGSLoadASI"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_divGSASITResult")))
start_date = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_generalSearchForm_txtGSStartDate")))
start_date.click()
start_date.send_keys("01/01/2023")
end_date = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_generalSearchForm_txtGSEndDate")))
end_date.click()
end_date.send_keys("01/05/2023")


res_commer_select = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_asiGSForm_NEVCO_ddl_0_0")))
res_commer_select.click()
#this line doesn't work:
res_commer_select.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: What does "does not execute" mean? Does the program exit? Do you get an error? Does it execute just fine, but just isn't doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: the program doesn't throw an error, but I can see the effects of the program in the browser--a particular value should be selected from the pick list, but I can see no effect from this line of code reflected in the browser unlike when I run the program in windows. Not sure how best to express this in the actual question I posted let me know if there is a better way to clarify.

Comment: So what _actual value_ do you see when you log the value of that code, on both operating systems?

Comment: Sorry I'm explaining this poorly but it is an HTML select field so I'm not actually seeing a "value" attribute, but there are 3 choices the default "--select--", "commercial", and "residential". In Windows I can actually see the UI update with the residental value whereas the Mac execution pauses and then exits after the select element is clicked and the dropdown options appear

Comment: When you state, "I have a bizarre error", people understandably expect that you actually encountered an error \*message\* and expect it to be part of the question. If you didn't actually get an error message, I would suggest you change your wording... perhaps, "I have a bizarre problem" or something similar.

Comment: updated the question you are correct--this is a difficult question to articulate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using down arrow in this case. That element, and several others on the page, are SELECT elements and create the dropdowns. There is a `Select` class in python to make working with them easier.

Your code

```
res_commer_select = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_asiGSForm_NEVCO_ddl_0_0")))
res_commer_select.click()
#this line doesn't work:
res_commer_select.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
```

should be

```
res_commer_select = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_asiGSForm_NEVCO_ddl_0_0"))))
res_commer_select.select_by_visible_text("Commercial")
```

with an import of

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

You might want to spend some time reading the docs, especially [this page](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms) since it covers `Select` and other info about filling in forms.

Comment: This works thank you! I will check out the documentation this is my first shot with selenium so it's very helpful to be pointed towards these resources, methods, functions, etc.!